# Leading zero for azimuths using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Azimuths are often written with a leading zero, e.g. NE as 045°. I am using the `siunitx` package to format all the other quantities in my document with the `\SI` macro, e.g.

```
\SI{100}{\metre}
```

but

```
\SI{45}{\degree}
```

comes out as 45°. What is the best way to produce 045°, but keeping the useful aspects that `siunitx` provides, like keeping the value and unit together with a nice spacing?

Edit: I might have figured this one out:

```
\SI[parse-numbers = false]{045}{\degree}
```

produces 045°.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get th emost out of our site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `\SI[parse-numbers = false]{045}{\degree}` works it also turns off all of `siunitx`'s parsing for that entry; to retain parsing try

```
\SI[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{45}{\degree}
```

As this is quite long you might like to define a new command `\azimuth`

```
\newcommand*{\azimuth}[1]{\SI[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{#1}{\degree}}
```

and use it `\azimuth{45}`.

If you want all numbers parsed by `siunitx` to have at least three integer digits, go with

```
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits = 3}
```

---

@Torbjørn T. mentioned that `siunitx` even provides a command for angles aptly named `\ang{}`.
So `\ang[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{45}` also does what you want.

---

The following definition of `\azimuth` always produces three digits for degree, two for minute and second.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__angle_print:nnn #1#2#3 {
  \IfNoValueF {#1}
    {\SI[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{#1}{\degree}}
  \IfNoValueF {#2}
    {\SI[minimum-integer-digits = 2]{#2}{\arcminute}}
  \IfNoValueF {#3}
    {\SI[minimum-integer-digits = 2]{#3}{\arcsecond}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \azimuth { > { \SplitArgument { 2 } { ; } } m } {
  \__angle_print:nnn #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Compare the output of `\azimuth{145;59;59} \azimuth{90;35;17} \azimuth{1;2;3}` with  `siunitx`'s `\ang{145;59;59} \ang{90;35;17} \ang{1;2;3}`:
[image]

Comment: As an addition you could mention `\ang[minimum-integer-digits=3]{45}`.