# siunitx table leading zeros

Tags: tables, errors, siunitx

How to preserve the leading zeros of the errors in a table using [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)' `S`-column type?

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}    
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}    
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{multi-part-units=single}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}    

\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-figures-decimal=1,
                        table-text-alignment=left,
                        table-number-alignment=left,
                        table-figures-uncertainty=1]}}
   \toprule
   A & {Column1 symbol $\Delta$} & {Column2 symbol $\delta$} \\
     & {Column1} & {Column2} \\
   \midrule
   B &  -5.0 \pm 1.0 & -10.0 \pm 02.0 \\
   C &   0.0 \pm 1.0 &   5.0 \pm 02.0 \\
   D & -20.0 \pm 1.0 & -100.0 \pm 20.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The closest you'll get is `minimum-integer-digits = 2`, but this applies to _all_ input. The package normalises input as a first step, so the unnecessary leading zeros are dropped before any formatting.

Comment: `minimum-integer-digits = 2` changes the numbers but has no effect on the errors.

Comment: this question might be helpful: [Leading zero for azimuths using siunitx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115882/579)

Answer (score 5):

The code in `siunitx` is broadly based around the idea that numbers will be normalised to a 'standard' form before printing. One of the normalisation rules is that leading zeros are removed. While there is some possibility to pad the integer part back out again, that's not the same as retaining 'excess' information in the input. As such, your best bet is to turn off the parser, as [suggested in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169042/siunitx-table-leading-zeros#comment389073_169042):

```
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
  english
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}    
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\sisetup{
  locale = DE,
  separate-uncertainty,
  multi-part-units = single
}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}    
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{parse-numbers = false}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    S[table-format = -2.1]
    @{${}\pm{}$}
    S[table-format =  1.1,table-number-alignment = left]
    S[table-format = -3.1]
    @{${}\pm{}$}
    S[table-format =  2.1,table-number-alignment = left]
  }
     \toprule
     A & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Column1 symbol $\Delta$}
       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Column2 symbol $\delta$} \\
       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Column1}
       & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Column2} \\
     \midrule
     B &  -5.0 & 1.0 &  -10.0 & 02.0 \\
     C &   0.0 & 1.0 &    5.0 & 02.0 \\
     D & -20.0 & 1.0 & -100.0 & 20.0 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```