# Retain Leading Zero in an Integer with Siunitx \num macro

Tags: siunitx

I would like to be able to retain a leading zero with the `siunitx` package.  That is using `\num{012345}` produces `12 345` but I would like to have `012 345`.

[image]

### References:

- [Siunitx table leading zeros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199990/4301) suggests to turn off the number parse (`parse-numbers=false`), but then the spacing between groups of three digits is also disabled.
- [Leading zero for azimuths using siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134639/4301) suggests to use `minimum-integer-digits = <n>` but that requires knowing how many digits there are.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Default Output: $012345 = \num{012345}$

Desired Output: $012345 = 012\,345$

\end{document}
```

Comment: One thing that came to mind now as I posted the question is to to typset the number as if it is a decimal number but suppress the decial point as well as the leading zero.

Comment: Would a LuaLaTeX-based solution be of interest to you?

Comment: @Mico: Not to me personally right now (but perhaps in the future).  I think it always useful to have different ways of doing things and may help others. Feel free to post. Even a `pgfprintnumber` option would be useful.  I have a solution working based on my above comment and will post a solution if no one else does.

Comment: What's your working assumption regarding the mininum number of digits needed to perform grouping by triples? Should grouping be performed as if the option `group-minimum-digits=4` were in place, or do you prefer the default, *viz.*, `group-minimum-digits=5`?

Comment: @Mico: Looks like you provided a parameter for this, but I prefer the 4 (which is what I thought the default was).

Comment: The default value of `group-minimum-digits` is actually `5`. However, I set it to `4` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

(modified the answer to allow setting the equivalent of the `group-minimum-digits` parameter of the `siunitx` package.

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a user-level LaTeX macro called `\Lnum`, which acts as a front end to a Lua function called `group_string`. This Lua function does virtually all of the work.

The equivalent of the `group-minimum-digits` parameter of the `siunitx` package -- generally, either `5` or `4` -- may be set in the optional argument of the `\Lnum` macro.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

%% Lua-side code: define a Lua function called 'group_string' 
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function group_string ( s , n )
   -- s: Input string -- usually, an integer.
   -- n: Minimum number of digits before grouping 
   --    is performed. This should be either 4 or 5.
   -- If s contains n or fewer characters, do nothing, 
   --    i.e., return the string s without modifications.
   -- Otherwise, insert thinspace into input string at 
   --    every third character, starting from the right. 
   -- Note: Leading zeros are preserved automatically.

   if string.len ( s ) < n then
       return s -- don't modify input string
   else 
       t = ""   -- initialize output string
       while string.len ( s ) > 3 do
           t =   "\\," .. string.sub ( s, -3 ) .. t
           s = string.sub ( s , 1, -4 ) -- drop last 3 chars
       end
       return s .. t
   end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: A user macro called "\Lnum".
%% Default value of optional argument of \Lnum 
%%   should be either 4 or 5.
\newcommand\Lnum[2][4]{\directlua{% 
    tex.sprint ( group_string ( "#2" , #1 ) )}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
input   & output         \\[1ex]
12345   & \Lnum{12345}   \\
012345  & \Lnum{012345}  \\
0000000 & \Lnum{0000000} \\
0123    & \Lnum{0123}    \\
0123    & \Lnum[5]{0123} \\ % set equivalent of 'group-minimum-digits' to 5
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```